React render JSX literal manaully
Trying to integrate a non-React library with React, and I want to display React components as children of the non-React library. I've got the non-React lib rendering no problem with useEffect, but I can't figure out how to display a React component as a child of that.
I thought I might be able to do something like createElement(props.slot), where slot is defined as a property like slot={<p>Slot content</p>}, but I get the error:

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: . Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?

The error is spot on, it is exactly what I did, but I don't know how to do what I'm looking for. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
p.s. I know this is isn't the "React" way to do it, but it will save rewriting the lib specifically for React :).
p.p.s Don't know if it helps, but in Vue I can use it's render() function to do something similar with h() vnodes.
